# Handle $stateparams in service or controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I integrated ui-router module into an angular application.

There are two ways to handle rest api with $stateParams, such like $stateParams.userId.

1. handle in controller, and pass into service function

controller.js

```
Post.createById($stateParams.userId)
    .then(...);
```

service.js

```
createcreateById: function(userId) {...}
```

2. just handle in service

controller.js

```
Post.createById()
    .then(...);
```

service.js

```
var id = $stateParams.userId
createById: function() {...}
```

What're pros & cons?

Comment: this is almost like asking what ink should I use, black, or blue? I personally would use the first approach. No real reason.

Comment: I use the first one too (wrote straightly). I m just curious about some examples in books used the second one.

Comment: You should go with first approach, you should no inject route relates dependencies in your services. Services should be free from it (so even if you want to separate the services module out of your angular scope, you can do it)